# Object not locked by thread before wait()

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I want this method to return response after the execution of my AsyncTask, this is my code, here Response is server response. I used task.wait() but I am getting this exception, Is there any other way to do this ? Thanks

```
 public Response postWithoutTokenXMLAsync(String url) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    JSON = MediaType.parse( "application/json; charset=utf-8" );

    client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().build();

    RequestBody body = RequestBody.create( JSON, "" );
    request = new Request.Builder()
            .url( url )
            .post( body )
            .build();

    task = new AsyncTask <String, String, Response>() {
        @Override
        protected Response doInBackground(String... strings) {
            try {
                response = client.newCall( request ).execute();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return response;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Response response) {
            super.onPostExecute( response );
        }

    };
    task.execute();

    task.wait();

    return response;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to put synchronized(task) around wait().   However, I believe you may be missing the understanding of wait().  wait() is to wait for another thread to fire a notify() event.

By trying to wait on the main thread, you are blocking the main thread.  It would be better to remove the AsyncTask from the code if you can block.   Otherwise need to provide a callback parameter into the method (rather than returning the result).  The method would then look as follows:

public void postWithoutTokenXMLAsync(String url, Consumer callback) throws IOException { ...

with code returning the result via   callback.accept(response) within the AsyncTask